# Button Position Issue

Tags: html, layout, button

ok so this is my code and the problem is that I have a buttons and a submit but for some unknown reason the text in the submit button is misplaced

here is the code

```
<input type="button"  id="openerCol" style = "width: 100px; height: 25px" value="Add new column" onclick="showPartial()"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="button"  id="openerInsCol" style = "width: 100px; height: 25px" value="Insert column" onclick="showPartial()"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="button"  id="openerUpCol" style = "width: 100px; height: 25px" value="Update column" onclick="showPartial()"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="button"  id="opener3" style = "width: 100px; height: 25px" value="Delete column" onclick="showPartial()"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" name="Index" style = "width: 100px;  text-align: top; height: 25px"; value="Add Row" />
 <br/>
 <input type="button"  id="openerDelR" style = "width: 100px; height: 25px" value="Delete row" onclick="showPartial()"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="button"  id="openerEditCell" style = "width: 100px; height: 25px" value="Edit cell" onclick="showPartial()"/>
```

here you can see the screen shot http://tinypic.com/r/rwpc48/6

any ideas?

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: the input type ="submit" is the problem you can see in the screenshot

Comment: the one with the value add row

Comment: I've tried to use "text-align: center" but no effect

Comment: I can't repro this one: it looks fine across IE9, FF and Chrome. Are there other styles that are being applied to that button, perhaps from a separate CSS file?

Comment: i have fount the problem it seems that if the type="submit" is the problem after I change it to button it's ok but unfortunately the type has to be submit

Answer (score 2):

you misplaced the semicolon in the style attribute. I've fix that line for you

```
 <input type="submit" name="Index" style = "width: 100px;  text-align: top; height: 25px;" value="Add Row" />
```

Comment: ok I fixed that but the problem remains the text is still in the same place

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem with `;` in `height: 25px";`

so just remove that semicolon.

I just copy and paste your code and it looks fine after removing the `;`.

Here is the demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JGcU/1/)

Comment: for some unknown reason for me it's the same

Answer (score 0):

```
style = "width: 100px;  text-align: top; height: 25px";
```

should be

```
style = "width: 100px;  text-align: top; height: 25px;"
```

Comment: that was not the problem or at least not the only one

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "text-align: top;" or try to copy all the properties of other buttons

Comment: if i change the type to button it's ok

Comment: May be you have CSS that override the text-align:top for submit.